# Yii2 rest api, название массива

Tags: php, json

Добрый день!

Дело такое, сделал я значит этот API для нашего IOS-ера, а он парится что у массива которую я ему отдаю нету названия. Примерно он выглядит вот так у меня

```
[
    {"name":"admin"}
]
```

, а он хочет чтобы это было так

```
[
    user:{"name":"admin"}
]
```

Как мне дать имя массиву?

Спасибо!

Comment: Пару вопросов. 1 Чем не нравится массив? 2. Почему он хочет невалидный JSON? Если давать имя массиву, то выглядеть должно так: `{"user" : [ {"name" : "admin" } ]}`

Answer (score 1):

При преобразовании в json, ассоциативные массивы преобразовываются в объекты, для получения массива в json, на входе должен быть индексный массив ключи которого идут по порядку, в противном случае будет создан объект. Поэтому вариант `[user:{"name":"admin"}]` невозможен, так как он является ассоциативным, вместо него можно получить лишь `{"user":{"name":"admin"}}`

```
//{"name":"admin"}
echo json_encode([
    'name' => 'admin',
]);

//[{"name":"admin"}]
echo json_encode([
    [
        'name' => 'admin',
    ]
]);

//{"user":{"name":"admin"}}
echo json_encode([
    'user' => [
        'name' => 'admin',
    ],
]);

//["name","admin"]
echo json_encode([
    0 => 'name',
    1 => 'admin',
]);

//{"1":"name","0":"admin"}
echo json_encode([
    1 => 'name',
    0 => 'admin',
]);

//{"user":[{"name":"admin"}]}
echo json_encode([
    'user' => [
        [
            'name' => 'admin',
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

> Как мне дать имя массиву?

```
{"user" : [ {"name" : "admin" } ]}
```

ответ взят из комментария. спасибо @VAndrJ